# header.php include only working on home (index.html) file

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add an include of "header.php" to my inside pages BUT my PHP syntax is showing up as a comment in chrome's editor.  The SAME "header.php" works fine on my home/ "index.html" page but will not on any other.  Some points to note:

- The route of "index.html" and "inside-page-example.html" are the same, so it's not a route problem.
- The code is not written as a comment in the file.  It reads:

`<?php include ('inc/header.php'); ?>`

So frustrating! :(

Comment: are you including a php file in your html file?

Comment: You have commented out the php part. That's why it's green.

Comment: you're trying to run php code in html file?? make the file `.php `extension and run it on a server

Comment: Your opening PHP tag is wrong in some way.  It should be `<?php`.  PHP isn't picking up on it causing it to be output directly, and Chrome is interpreting it as a comment.  In any case, if you want better advice you should post your code.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
<!--?php ... ?-->
```

Try:

```
<?php ... ?>
```

and also change your file extension to .php (everywhere you are using php)

Answer (score 0):

You do need to take out the comments, so that it's just `<?php` and `?>`. The green text in Chrome indicates that it is being read as a comment.

You'll also need to save the file as `.html` with filetype as "Hypertext Markup Language" not just `.txt`, but I have a feeling you have that covered.

Also, you'll need to make sure that every file is in the same folder. If "inside-page-example.php" is inside a different folder, then you will need to add a forward slash or `/../` for every folder you want to go up. So if you have header.php and index.php and a folder called Resume all inside "Home" folder, then when you are on Resume/index.php, you'll need to say `include_once("/header.php");`. A really great tool that I use when using includes is to replace the slashes with `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]`. So the include would read like this: `include_once("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/header.php");`. This will grab header.php from the folder at the root of the server. Does that make more sense?